# Author's Diction

Tags: diction

I thought that these sentences would be considered informal, but my friend argued that they are semi‑formal. Can anybody help us decide?

1. > I live in western South Dakota [. . . .] For several years, I spent winters alone here.

   I thought this was informal because it was too personal for a professional essay.
2. > . . .but there is no point in having a gun—in fact, gun possession might increase your danger—unless you know you can use it.

   I thought this was informal because of the “in fact”.
3. > . . .resent the idea that just because I am female. . .

   I thought this was informal because of the "just because".

Comment: Your friend is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. “I live in western South Dakota [. . . .] **F**or several years, **I** spent winters alone here.”

After the punctuation changes and the capitalisation of the ‘i’, there is nothing particularly informal about the language of these sentences. Your personal experiences might be out of place in an essay on the advantages and disadvantages of South Dakota as a holiday venue, but that's nothing to do with the formality of the grammar or syntax.